# Generate beautiful summary table output for lmer models in R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a lot of lmer models with a `summary()` output that looks like this (usually with more variables, this was just a very quick nonsense example I generated):

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: mpg ~ cyl + hp + disp * drat + (1 | gear) + (1 | carb)
   Data: mtcars

REML criterion at convergence: 171.8

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.4583 -0.5671 -0.2118  0.3912  2.1303 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 carb     (Intercept) 2.07353  1.4400  
 gear     (Intercept) 0.04659  0.2158  
 Residual             7.63829  2.7637  
Number of obs: 32, groups:  carb, 6; gear, 3

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  6.27454   11.75344 25.17470   0.534   0.5981  
cyl         -0.30519    0.84443 25.55852  -0.361   0.7208  
hp          -0.01412    0.01798 10.10227  -0.785   0.4503  
disp         0.03101    0.03649 23.25810   0.850   0.4041  
drat         5.97395    2.65430 24.44199   2.251   0.0337 *
disp:drat   -0.01380    0.01172 24.05299  -1.178   0.2503  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
          (Intr) cyl    hp     disp   drat  
cyl       -0.512                            
hp        -0.087 -0.337                     
disp      -0.710 -0.021  0.341              
drat      -0.965  0.317  0.142  0.823       
disp:drat  0.698 -0.131 -0.461 -0.950 -0.778
convergence code: 0
Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0112263 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
```

Is there a way to generate a `summary()` output with all of this information, but nicely formatted for RMarkdown? I've found a variety of solutions for Markdown (e.g. `kable`, `huxtable`, `pander`), but most of them are only able to display for example the Fixed Effects table. In those examples, the Signif. codes stars (`*`-`***`) are usually also not shown.

I'm looking for a function that gives me an output just like this, but formatted for RMarkdown and including the significance codes.

Comment: I don't know an easy way to get eery bit of this info, but have you seen functions in package **broom** (and **broom.mixed**)?  You can certainly opt to get more than the fixed effects for merMod objects but I'm not sure how much.

Comment: I like `jtools::export_summs()` for this. Sometimes it doesn't show the p *'s, but usually there is a sound reason for this.